# Form is submitting when the page loads

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a really simple Rails app. Basically an article with comments. I want the article page to show the article, comments underneath and then a textbox to write a comment and a submit button to submit it.

I got it all working except for one (big) problem. When the page loads.. example.com/article/1
 a blank comment is submitted to the database.

I fixed that by including "validates_presence_of :body" in the Comment model. But that results in the following image when the page loads:

[image]

This is my code by the way:

```
def show
@place = Article.find(params[:id])
@comment = Article.find(params[:id]).comments.create(params[:comment])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @article }
end
  end
```

and

```
    <% form_for([@article, @comment]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you made a create.

Create try save object and like is invalid, an error is generate.

Made :
`@comment = Article.find(params[:id]).comments.build(params[:comment])`

Fix your problem I think